# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model_db' using django.setup() outside django project

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im trying to use django ORM on a project, im using django 5.0.1,

i read to acomplish i need this configuration, this would be on main.py:

[the link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from DATABASE.Django_ORM.Django_ORM import settings as st


settings.configure(default_settings=st, DEBUG=True)
django.setup()

#Importing Models
from DATABASE.Django_ORM.model_db import models
```

However it returns a Error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model_db'

model_db is the app i create on django

here is the settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'model_db',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Django_ORM.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Django_ORM.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

LOGGING_CONFIG = None
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = None
LOGGING = None
```

The project entire structure would be like this:

```
ª   .env
ª   .gitignore
ª   main.py
ª   tree.txt
ª   __init__.py
ª   
+---DATABASE
ª   ª   __init__.py
ª   ª   
ª   +---Django_ORM
ª   ª   ª   db.sqlite3
ª   ª   ª   manage.py
ª   ª   ª   
ª   ª   +---Django_ORM
ª   ª   ª   ª   .env
ª   ª   ª   ª   asgi.py
ª   ª   ª   ª   settings.py
ª   ª   ª   ª   urls.py
ª   ª   ª   ª   wsgi.py
ª   ª   ª   ª   __init__.py
ª   ª   ª   ª   
ª   ª   ª   +---__pycache__
ª   ª   ª           settings.cpython-312.pyc
ª   ª   ª           urls.cpython-312.pyc
ª   ª   ª           wsgi.cpython-312.pyc
ª   ª   ª           __init__.cpython-312.pyc
ª   ª   ª           
ª   ª   +---model_db
ª   ª       ª   apps.py
ª   ª       ª   models.py
ª   ª       ª   __init__.py
ª   ª       ª   
ª   ª       +---migrations
ª   ª       ª   ª   0001_initial.py
ª   ª       ª   ª   __init__.py
ª   ª       ª   ª   
ª   ª       ª   +---__pycache__
ª   ª       ª           0001_initial.cpython-312.pyc
ª   ª       ª           __init__.cpython-312.pyc
ª   ª       ª           
ª   ª       +---__pycache__
ª   ª               admin.cpython-312.pyc
ª   ª               apps.cpython-312.pyc
ª   ª               models.cpython-312.pyc
ª   ª               __init__.cpython-312.pyc
ª   ª               
ª   +---__pycache__
ª           __init__.cpython-312.pyc
ª           
+---Environ
+---Input_Configuration
ª       orders.py
ª       __init__.py
ª
```

I don't know why its not detecting model_db because is added to the installed apps dict on settings

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with directories. Try something like this

```
import django
import os
import sys
PWD = os.getenv('PWD')
os.chdir(PWD)
sys.path.insert(0, os.getenv('PWD'))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PROJECT.settings")
django.setup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Angela for the answer, it was a directory problem, here is the solution:

```py
import django
import os

from Django_ORM import settings_bot as st
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Django_ORM.settings')
django.setup()
#Importing Models
from model_db import models
```

Also here is another [link](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-orm-as-a-standalone-library/4971) who helped